# Electrumx server not showing data when running RPC Query command

Tags: bitcoin

I'm running a full bitcoin node and an Electrumx server on the same machine.  The Electrumx server is running and is caught up to the latest blocks, I can run electrumx_rpc getinfo and it returns the info as it should, but when I run the electrumx_rpc query on an address or a hash I don't get any information on my query results.

Exp: (random bitcoin address)

```
    ~/source/electrumx$ electrumx_rpc query 329cM9Yfnpc7Wfgy6UPmyXfxbGUy38v5hH
    address
    history
    utxos
    balance
```

I'm not sure why it's not returning any data.

my journalctl output shows this when I run it:

```
    May 24 10:24:42 Satoshi-III electrumx_server[1876]: INFO:LocalRPC:[54] RPC xx.xx.xx.xx:xx, 0 total
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, I had to email the dev.  There was a bug in the latest version.  He updated the git HEAD.  I downloaded that version and now it's now working.

from the Dev:

"Yeah it seems like the guy who did the PR in March broke it.... I've reverted it in git HEAD."